# Notation for $G$-sets

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, notation, etale-cohomology

For a group $G$ and a $G$-set $M$, I am not entirely sure what the notation $M^G$ means.

For context: Over a field $k$, if $\mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf of abelian groups over $X=(\operatorname{Spec}k)_{\acute{e}tale}$ that corresponds to the to the $G$-set $M$, then $H^0_{\acute{e}tale}(X,\mathcal{F})=M^G$ ([Stack 03QU](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03QU)). Here, $G=Gal(k^{sep}/k)$.

Could someone please help tell me the exact definition of this notation?

Edit: The question has been answered in the comments

Comment: $M^G$ denotes the set of elements of $M$ fixed by the action of $G$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: To clear any possible ambiguity, I'd always prefer something like "$M^G:=$ ...".